# How to set User Defauts from command line arugment when it is "set of strings"

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to set User defaults value from command line.
I found the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html) about the User defaults and how to pass a value via command line.
What I'm trying to do now is pass the "set of strings" as the value to an application.
More speicfically, I want to run XCode(4.2) with PBExtraPlugInFolders set.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html) is the User Defaults of XCode and it says PBExtraPlugInFolders is "set of string".

What I have tried so far is following command which does not work.

```
/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -PBExtraPlugInFolders /PluginFolder
```

I also tried following command which also do not work.

```
/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -PBExtraPlugInFolders /PluginFolder/myplugin.bundle
/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -PBExtraPlugInFolders "/PluginFolder"
/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -PBExtraPlugInFolders "/PluginFolder/myplugin.bundle"
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array of values enclosed with brackets separated with commas, like `'("/path/you/want")'`.

To examine that you can run e.g. `defaults read -app Xcode` and look examples for all possible types in many variations; also command `defaults read-type -app Xcode InterestingKey` will show you type of value for InteresingKey.

But I don't think this key is still relevant.